# XML parsing via SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to parser below XML with the mentioned code. But results are blank.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn AS XML 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\GET_QUOTA_DATA_resTEST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

SELECT 
BucketBucket_id = bucket.value('(bucket_id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
BucketName = bucket.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM
@XmlFile.nodes('/bucket') AS XTbl1(bucket)
```

XML is as below

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:toa:capacity">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns1:get_quota_data_response>
            <bucket>
             <bucket_id>FT_10503_DP1019</bucket_id>
             <name>ABC Co</name>
                <day>
                    <date>2015-08-21</date>
                </day>
           </bucket>
      </ns1:get_quota_data_response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is that all XML? It is not correctly formed. Try SELECT @XmlFile/PRINT @XmlFile.  Describe also desired result.

Comment: @lad2025 It's fine above I haven't put the whole XML may be that's why. Updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT 
     BucketBucket_id = bucket.value('(bucket_id)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
     BucketName = bucket.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
 FROM 
     @XmlFile.nodes('//bucket') AS XTbl1(bucket)
```

You used `/bucket` which is direct path from root. That's why it didn't work.

- `/` will define an absolute path to node "a" relative to the root
- `//` will define a path to node "a" anywhere within the XML document

Comment: Excellent `// ` made the difference.